# Self provoked buffer overflow in C

Tags: c

I was wondering if it's possible to generate a buffer overflow programmatically, I mean, without any user input.

I've been trying to cause a buffer overflow with the `memcpy` function, copying the content of a buffer into another of smaller size. Now, the segmentation fault only triggers when the source buffer is initialized as follows:

```
char * overflow = "\x40\40\x40...";
```

or:

```
char * overflow = {"\x40\40\x40..."};
```

If I copy this buffer into another variable of smaller size, it overflows it successfully. But this kind of declaration makes the source buffer read-only, so I was wondering if it's possible to dynamically generate the content of the buffer so that, for instance, the program can generate a buffer in runtime that can redirect the instruction pointer to some memory address calculated in runtime aswell. So I've tried to change it to:

```
char overflow[] = {"\x40\x40\x40\x40..."}
```

However, this declaration doesn't trigger the segmentation fault for some reason I don't understand very well, no matter how long the buffer is.

Why read-only constant strings can trigger the buffer overflow, but variables can't?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
int WINAPI mainCRTStartup(){
  char buffer[100];
  char * overflow = {   "\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40"
    "\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40"
    "\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40"
    "\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40"
    "\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40"
    "\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x64\x63\x62\x61\x40\x40\x40\x40"
    "\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40"
    "\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40"
    "\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40"
    "\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40\x40"
  };

  printf("Ready:\n");
  // 117
  memcpy(buffer, overflow, 117);
  //strcpy(buffer, overflow);
  printf("String: %s\n", buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it with:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -O2 -s -DNDEBUG -static \
    -nostdlib -m32 \
    -o deleteme.exe deleteme.c \
    -lkernel32 -lmsvcrt -fno-stack-protector
```

This code successfully sets the instruction pointer to the address 0x61626364.
I know this might not have any practical use, I'm just curious about this behavior.

Comment: Buffer overflows don't always cause segmentation faults.

Comment: Where is `char overflow[]` in the code?

Comment: A likely scenario is that `char overflow[] = …;` creates a large array on the stack, just next to `char buffer[100];`. Then, when you copy `overflow` into `buffer`, the writing overflows from `buffer` into `overflow`, where it overwrites harmless data, never reaching the more sensitive data further up the stack. In contrast, with `char *overflow = …;`, `overflow` points to read-only data somewhere else in the process’ address space, and the stack frame is smaller, so the `memcpy` into `buffer` does reach the sensitive data.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks man, that's what was happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `char overflow[]`, the memory for the `overflow` array is in the same stack frame as `buffer`, and it's probably located right after it. So when you exceed the bounds of `buffer`, you're writing back into `overflow`, not overwriting the return address field in the stack frame.

Make it `static char overflow[]`, or make `overflow` a global variable. Then it won't be in the stack frame. You could also just try changing the order of the two variable declarations.